# Git, find out in which timezone most lines commited in a file

Tags: git, timezone

I cloned a git repository. What's the simplest way to find out the timezone where most of the lines in a specific file (or specific multiple files) were committed? I used `git log --pretty=format:"%cd" filename` but if there are many commits it's a mess to find out.

Answer (score 2):

That's a good start. I don't think Git alone has a convenient mechanism to get the output you want, but some shell scripting should do the trick - extract the timezone, count the number of times each timezone appears, and sort in a descending order:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%cd" somefile.txt | cut -d" " -f6 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Comment: What about DST?

Comment: I find out that I must use git blame

Comment: how can the columns for this be swapped?

Comment: @user18348324 you can use whatever format you want

Comment: @Mureinik i meant that `sort -nr` shows the count on the left-side and the timezone on the right-hand side, and I would like it the opposite.

Comment: @user18348324 I'm not aware of a way to do this directly with `sort`, but you could pipe the result into `awk` to achieve that effect: `| awk '{ print $2 " " $1}'`. I.e., the full command line would be `git log --pretty=format:"%cd" index.js | cut -d" " -f6 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | awk '{ print $2 " " $1}'`

Answer (score 0):

With git blame, the answer would be as follows and worked well:

```
git blame --line-porcelain FILENAME |
grep '^committer-tz' |
sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

If you really just want the single timezone, you could expand it to:

```
git blame --line-porcelain FILENAME |
grep '^committer-tz' |
sort | uniq -c | sort -rn |
head -n 1 | egrep -o "(+|-)[0-9]{4}"
```